# PHP функция прибавления 1 месяца к unix через strtotime, как вывести 1 число?

Tags: php, дата, unix

У меня задача, прибавить к месяцу +1 месяц. Т.е 31 января + 1 месяц = 1 марта. Если допустим в текущем месяце больше дней, чем в следующем, то в следующем поставить на 1 число
Функция strtotime("+1 month") вообще выводит 3 марта. Если я буду каждый месяц прибавлять так 1 месяц, то через год я получу не 31 января, а 3 февраля.

Comment: *прибавить к месяцу +1 месяц. Т.е 31 января + 1 месяц = 1 марта.* Это прибавить месяц (получится 28 или 29 февраля) и ещё 1 день.

Comment: не получится, в моем случаи выводит 3 марта

Comment: Я не говорю о результате Ваших вычислений. Я о том, что у Вас задача расходится с желаемым результатом.

Comment: так в чем сложность реализовать прям непосредственно указанный алгоритм? есть текущая дата. Берем следующий месяц, смотрим там число дней. Если текущий день в следующий месяц попадает, то оставляем. Есои не попадаем то на первое число. вроде несколько строк кода надо, или что?

Comment: Тут еще надо определиться как надо вести на граничных случаях, к примеру что будет при 30.11.2020 +1м (последний день месяца) - 30.12.2020 или 31.12.2020, дальше 31.01.2021 + 1м (последний день месяца) - 28.02.2021 (или 29 в высокосном), а 30.01.2021 + 1м (предпоследний день) - тоже ведь в феврале нет, тоже 28.02.2021 или 27.02.2021 (предпоследний день февраля)

Answer (score 0):

Читайте документацию. `strtotime('first day of next month')`